# Fitting Gatheral's SVI model

Tags: options, implied-volatility, volatility-skew, curve-fitting

I was considering using [Gatheral's formula](http://faculty.baruch.cuny.edu/jgatheral/madrid2004.pdf) for fitting option skew. In the specific (commodity) market that I am concerned with, the underlying is ca. at 50, and typically 5 integer strikes left and right of that would be observable, i.e. $k$ ranges from ca. -0.1 to +0.1. I really struggle to get a stable fit on this... I am wondering if this is down to the data just not really being enough for fitting this 5-parameter function (which i guess is the case), or is it just me not using well-chosen start values for the fit. I was hoping there would be seasoned practitioners to comment on this.

I have the following variance plot:
[image]

with above 2nd order polynomial fit, I get $p_t=-0.0015$, $c_t=-1.7146e-04$, $\psi_t=-8.1992e-04$ $b=-1.2818e-04$, $\rho=-0.7950$, and that means $\beta\notin [-1,1]$

Comment: Hi @ZRH, maybe it would help to have an example of the smile you are trying to fit. Could you provide $(K, \sigma(K))$ couples?

Comment: @Quantuple sure. Strikes were: 67.5,70,72.5,75,77.5,80,82.5,85,87.5,90,92.5, Vols in %: 22.14,20.99,19.61,19.16,18.57,17.73,17.11,16.60,16.20,15.73,15.37

Comment: Defining $k=log(K/80)$ as the log-forward moneyness for your problem, I find that raw SVI parameters $(a,b,\rho,m,\sigma)= (-0.0511,0.2613,-0.8375,-0.3383,0.4944)$ provide a good fit. My objective function is sum of squares type + a penalisation for absence of static arbitrage.I do work in a modified parameter space to account for constraints on the definition domain of the representation. Also, I determine the initial guess in the Jump-Wings SVI space (see section 3.3 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.0646.pdf), since parameters bear a more straightforward interpretation in that space.

Comment: ok - that is way more advanced than my current approach. Thanks for the ref !

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @Quantuple: With the data I have provided, both $p_t$ and $c_t$ are negative, and esp the condition mentioned in the footnote on page 8 is violated ($-p_t<2 \psi_{t}<c_t$), leading to problems with the condition that $\beta\in[-1,1]$

Comment: Which svi model are you using? The parameters you mention don't line up with any of the specific models in the first part of the paper (raw, natural, jump wings), but look like somewhat of a mix. If you're using jump wings, then you'll have the issue that it's not well defined in your case, since you don't have a minimum in the smile. @quantuple - when you refer to the modified parameter space, are you refering to the zeliade method?

Comment: @will: This is precisely the issue i have. I come across a lot of data, where the skew is so predominant that i dont see a minimum. I believe that if I had a minimum, I would also get a fit using the raw parameters to converge

Comment: @will Hi. No, just that I'm using an unconstrained local optimiser. Thus I need to work in a modified parameter space to account for constraints such as box constraints for the correlation parameter or the fact that minimum variance should be positive. But I agree with your analysis, an infinite amount of smile could fit here. Getting a "good" fit is easy, but one that makes sense financially requires more knowledge about the market.